# Filter a dataset or datatable .net 2.0

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataset

I have to fix something in a .net 2 application and I need to filter a dataset or datatable.

Basically an xml file is read into a dataset and there are inner tables of some parts of the xml with the same name.

EG Customer has table called order and  Employee has table called order

now given that this xml is now a dataset how do i filter based on child relationship or

"give all the orders that belong to the customer table"

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Dataview` for this purpose. Considering the fact that `Order` table has column named `Ordered_Entity` (for example) which defines the specific entity made the order then you can do like

```
DataView dv = new DataView(YourOrderTable);
dv.RowFilter = "Ordered_Entity = 'customer'";
```

Comment: In case the answer doesn't fits then consider posting the schema present in your DataSet.